# datetime.date object is not callable

Tags: python

**Hello**, so my issue is what I think is I can't call function twice. I want to loop through all saturdays in different years and use those dates to change date of reports.

Process gets through year 2020 but can't get through year 2021 for some reason. And I'm getting these errors:

1. line 19, in <module.>,
   AllSundaysDates = list(allSundays(processYear))
2. line 9, in allSundays,
   d = date(year, 1, 1), TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not callable

Like I'm not able to rewrite d with different year

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import datetime

monthsInYearList = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
yearsToDownload = [2020, 2021]
arrReportsList = ['COUNTRY_RETAILER_PET_DOG_PLUS','COUNTRY_RETAILER_PET_CAT_PLUS','COUNTRY_RETAILER_FOOD','COUNTRY_RETAILER_GRO','COUNTRY_RETAILER_CONF']

def allSundays(year):
    d = date(year, 1, 1)
    d += timedelta(days = 5 -d.weekday())
    while d.year == year:
        yield d
        d += timedelta(days=7)
        
#Loop in all years    
for processYear in yearsToDownload:   
    print ("Processing year:",processYear)
    #All sundays in given year
    AllSundaysDates = list(allSundays(processYear))
    #Loop in months
    for sMonth in monthsInYearList:
        #index of month Jan=1 Feb=2
        monthIndex = monthsInYearList.index(sMonth)+1
        print("Processing month:",sMonth)
        #Clear list
        monthDatesList = []
        #Loop trough all sundays
        for d in AllSundaysDates:
            devidedDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(d), "%Y-%m-%d")
            #Process only given Month
            if (monthIndex == devidedDate.month):
                #Write given date to list
                monthDatesList.append(d)
        #Loop trough reports                
        for sReportName in arrReportsList:
            #Write reportName
            print("----------------------")
            print(sReportName+": ")
            print("----------------------")
            #Write found dates
            for date in monthDatesList:
                print(date)
```

But when I tried to get rid of any unnecessary code it works just fine and I can get through 2020 and 2021 with no issue.

```
for processYear in yearsToDownload:
    AllSundaysDates = list(allSundays(processYear))
    for sundayDate in AllSundaysDates:
        print (sundayDate)
```

**My question is:**
Why process does not allow me to use different year in big code but when I use smaller one it works ?

If you got any suggestions how to fix this, please let me know. Thank you.

Wish you wonderful life, kind regards
**-lostDove 999**

Comment: You're defining a global variable called `date` (in `for date in ...`) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last for loop of your code:

```
for date in monthDatesList:
    print(date)
```

you are reassigning the `datetime` module's `date` function to an element in `monthDatesList`. I would rename it to something like `monthDate` to make sure you're not overwriting the `date` function. Always be careful when naming variables to not overwrite anything you're importing